# Why are my private vars being changed?

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, private

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xh4GU/1
or the code:

```
function Vector()
{
    var v = new Array(123, 456, 789);

    this.getV = function()
    {
        return v;
    }
}

function Formulas()
{
    this.add = function(x, axis, units)
    {
        x[axis] += units;
    }
}

var vector = new Vector();
var formulas = new Formulas();

var v = vector.getV();
var vAdded = formulas.add(v, 0, 77)

document.write(v);
```

spits out: 200,456,789

Why is the first index of v being changed?
Thanks

Comment: Because all your variables (`v`, global `v`, `x` parameter) reference the same array object? What did you expect `add` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because <strike>the array is passed to `formulas.add` by reference</strike> the argument being passed `formulas.add` is a reference to the private array `v`, any changes you make to its contents will remain visible in the future.

The fact that `v` is private doesn't protect its contents when you hand out references to `v` to external code. It does prevent external code from grabbing `v` for itself and swapping `v` with another array, but the array itself can be modified (its values changed).

Comment: JavaScript only has pass-by-value, even if those values are objects.

Comment: Yes there is no pass-by-reference in JavaScript.  Values that happen to be references to objects are passed by value :-)

Comment: @Bergi _Wrong_, please see: http://www.snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass/ for comprehensive examples.

Comment: @A.M.K: No. Please understand what [pass by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass-by-reference#Call_by_reference) actually is. JavaScript only has pass-by-value; whatever you do inside the function the *variable* outside doesn't change its value. Of course both may reference the same object, and changes to properties will be "reflected". JavaScript does [call-by-sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass-by-reference#Call_by_sharing) for objects

Comment: @A.M.K The ability to pass (by value) a reference to a mutable object does not constitute "pass by reference".  The term has a very specific meaning.

Comment: @A.M.K Also that link you posted is ancient and filled with questionable information.

Comment: @Bergi: I fixed the wording, and although the original is not technically accurate IMHO it does convey the point that in the end you are operating on a reference to the original array.

Comment: @A.M.K well understand that the term "pass by reference" has a **very** precise meaning. It does not mean "the ability to pass a reference to a mutable object".  It means that it's possible to have a function modify the value of a variable in another context.  It's nice and convenient that JavaScript allows the passing of references to mutable objects, but it's simply not the same thing as "pass by reference".

Comment: @A.M.K Actually I **can** say that, because "pass by reference" is a very specific term in programming language design. In JavaScript, the value of a variable that refers to an object is like a pointer to that object. The pointer is passed by value to functions.  That's what the terminology means.

Comment: @A.M.K well, it actually is inherently wrong. Terminology is important, and **there is no pass by reference in JavaScript.**

Comment: @A.M.K Read section 11.2.3 of the spec, which clearly elucidates the fact that parameters to functions are always fully-evaluated expressions ("r-values").  You can't simply invent a new meaning for a well-understood term like "pass by reference". (*edit*) your "conclusion" is simply incorrect; this is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: @A.M.K in Chemistry, there is no room for alternative meaning to the term "covalent bond". In Geology, there is no alternative meaning to "ultramafic rock".  Similarly, in Computer Science, there is no alternative meaning to the term "pass by reference"

Comment: @A.M.K well that's certainly true, and I endorse your freedom do to and think as you please, but it's nevertheless true that terminology in Computer Science sometimes has specific meaning, and this is one of those times. The term "pass by reference" (or "call by reference") definitely has a specific meaning, and JavaScript doesn't do it.  C++ does: that's what the `&` is all about.

Comment: @A.M.K If you don't change your mind, you will continue to have an incorrect understanding of the term "pass by reference." If you're serious about understanding Computer Science, you really need to figure this out. It's not a matter of opinion. If you don't really care about understanding Computer Science, then it all doesn't matter :-)

Comment: @Pointy I'll look into the subject, I don't know C++ and JavaScript is a much less strict language so I haven't had a need for the knowledge.


 I'm also only 13 so I don't have an actual coding education, I figured everything that I know out by myself. I am going to delete my side of this discussion as it's quite a clutter.

Comment: @A.M.K well now I'm embarrassed :-) To have gotten this far in this silly argument at age 13, I'd say you're doing OK!  I wish you a happy and successful future in software or whatever you choose to do.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you! But it's hardly a silly argument. Another point is that [call-by-sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass-by-reference#Call_by_sharing) is _inside_ the call-by-reference article... But, again, this is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for the 'pass by' info guys. It's a great starting point to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Because you changing it v is an array and you are changing it in Formulas. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh4GU/2/)

```
var vector = new Vector();
document.write(v.toString());  // 123,456,789
var formulas = new Formulas();

var v = vector.getV();
var vAdded = formulas.add(v, 0, 77).// v getting changed inside formulas.add.  
document.write(v); //200,456,789
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var vAdded = formulas.add(v, 0, 77)
```

You're saying to add the first index of the array (`v[0]`) by 77. Why? The private variable `v` is returned by `this.getV`. When you did

```
var v = vector.getV();
```

it returned a reference to the array. This effectively allows you to interact with the array outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are *referencing* not copying `v`, please see my demo for a more clear-cut example: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/hjtLd/ If you click the button after it generates the numbers you will see that the result is a different array.

However, if you move the array to inside `vector.getV()` you will see that the result will consistently be 123,456,789. This is because you would be resetting the value of `v` every time the function is run.

You could also create a "real" copy, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/J8h4d/